# If the age is older than 18, then save the Customer record

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, select, sql-function

I want to create a function, which checks the age from by the entry a record. if the age is older than 18, then save the record. If not, don't save the record.

```
create function f_Over18 (@age date)
returns char (20)

as begin 
    --declare @returnOne int
    declare @date int
    set @date= year(getdate()) - year(@age)
    if (@date > 17)
        begin 
            print ('Age verified') --this is only an example but i want, that safes the record
        end
    else
        begin
            print ('Age not verified')
        end;
end;
```

Thanks a lot for your kind help.

Comment: Getting the difference in the years isn't the right way to work out someone's age. Someone born on 31 December 2000 isn't 18 on 01 January 2018 (they are 17 and a day old), but 2018 - 2000 is 18. There are, however, 100's of examples on how calculate age in SQL Server here, have you had a look at those?

Comment: thanks for your reply! i had not idea how to work and write a better function. i have searched a lot but couldn't find the right one. what i want is, the data type of birthday of a column should be this function. if the entry (birthdate) is older than 18, then this function allows the record to be safed, if not, then ignores it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question really is about how to compute an age from a date of birth in SQL Server. It is not that easy, since there is no built-in for that, and because functions such as `datediff()` cannot really give an accurate results (or at least not without many convolutions).

A simple and efficient method is to convert the date of birth and the current date to format `YYYYMMDD`, turn that to a string, then use simple arithmetics, like so:

```
(convert(int, convert(char(8), getdate(), 112)) - convert(char(8), @dob, 112)) / 10000
```

In your function:

```
create function f_Over18 (@dob date)
returns nvarchar (20)
as begin 
    declare @age int;
    declare @res nvarchar(20);
    set @age= 
        (convert(int, convert(char(8), getdate(), 112)) - convert(char(8), @dob, 112)) 
        / 10000;

    if (@age > 17)
        begin 
            set @res = 'Age verified';
        end
    else
        begin
            set @res = 'Age not verified';
        end;

    return concat(@res, ': ', @age);
end;
```

I slightly modified the original code so it compiles properly, and returns the computed date as well (which makes it easy to debug).

Now **[we can test](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=38c3379726f12b9730ab0190a3bb566c)**:

```
dob        | res                 
:--------- | :-------------------
2000-01-01 | Age verified: 20    
2002-06-11 | Age verified: 18    
2002-06-13 | Age not verified: 17
2010-01-01 | Age not verified: 10
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. can i not use a user defined function in this way? 
create table test (first_name varchar (20), birthdate f_Over18());
Because, for me shows error!

Comment: @Patrick: no you can't do that. And even if you could, keep in mind that ages do change over time, so this is not an information that you want to store. Anyway, what you are asking now is a different question, so you should probably [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), providing a clear view of your requirement.